# Google Cast SDK works only with Chromecast or can it work with any Smart TV?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have a question about Google Cast sdk.

1. Does the sdk allows android phone to connect to any Smart TV (without built in Chromecast) OR it allows connection with Chromecast ONLY?

I have an app which plays video content (News, Sports etc) and i want that to be played on any Smart TV irrespective of the manufacturer. Can i do it with the cast sdk? If not, Is it possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cast SDK only supports cast devices (that includes variations of chromecast, chromecast for audio, cast tvs, android tvs, some sound bars, etc). Smart TVs use their own framework and Google Cast SDK does not support them.

Comment: I'll note here that the current Youtube app (iOS) can ("chrome")cast to a 2019 US Samsung Smart-TV. There is no chromecast attached to the tv. Oh it has Airplay 2 also.